# Is it me or are most or all new questions "off topic"?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, unanswered-questions

It could just be bad timing but it seems to me that almost all the new questions are third-party plugin or theme/CSS questions (all technically off-topic).

What can we do about this and is there anything I can do (aside from flagging them and adding a comment about what the community is looking for)?

Comment: We did recently push to have the Question Draft [sidebar box modified](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4672/7355) to include a description of on-topic/off-topic information. I guess nobody reads that :(

Comment: Is [this kind of question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/364004/in-acf-create-list-of-terms-to-be-selected-by-another-acf-option-elsewhere-is) also `off-topic`? It seems to be a plugin usage question according to the rule. Am I right?

Comment: @simongcc IMO I would say the question you referenced is off-topic, it could probably be re-worded to be more on-topic.  But having "In ACF..." in the title and mentioning the plugin several times is probably why it got flagged.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis Agree. Then maybe I try to help to rephrase them when possible. But the content itself is usually plugin-centric. Users tend to comes here for any WordPress related matters. Some of them even expect come and paste then work and turn away...LOL